# $P(X=x, Y=y)= e^{-2}\binom{x}{y} \frac{3}{4}^{y}\frac{1}{4}^{x-y}\frac{2^{x}}{x!}$ ; Then $E(Y)$?

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

Let the random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the joint probability mass function
$$P(X=x, Y=y)= e^{-2}\binom{x}{y} \dfrac{3}{4}^{y}\frac{1}{4}^{x-y}\frac{2^{x}}{x!} ; \ \ y=0,1,...x ; x = 0,1,2...$$

Then $E(Y)$?

I tried to simplify this but couldn't. I can see one part is of binomial other is of Poisson with parameter $2$ but they are not independent so that is not gonna help me. How should i simplify it ?

Comment: No problem, this is enough to go on. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's too hard to find the marginals, write
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[Y] &= \sum_{\text{all x}}\sum_{\text{all }y}y \cdot \mathbb{P}(X = x, Y = y)\\
&=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\sum_{y=0}^{x}y\cdot e^{-2}\binom{x}{y}\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^y\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^{x-y}\dfrac{2^x}{x!} \\
&= \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}e^{-2}\dfrac{2^x}{x!}\left[\sum_{y=0}^{x}y\binom{x}{y}\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^y\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^{x-y}\right]
\end{align}$$
The sum 
$$\sum_{y=0}^{x}y\binom{x}{y}\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^y\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^{x-y}$$
is the expected value of a binomial distribution based on $x$ trials and "success" probability $3/4$. Hence, 
$$\sum_{y=0}^{x}y\binom{x}{y}\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^y\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^{x-y} = x\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)$$
Thus,
$$\mathbb{E}[Y]=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}e^{-2}\dfrac{2^x}{x!}x\dfrac{3}{4}=\dfrac{3}{4}\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}x\cdot\dfrac{e^{-2}2^x}{x!}$$
The sum 
$$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}x\cdot\dfrac{e^{-2}2^x}{x!}$$
is the expected value of a Poisson distribution with parameter $2$, hence we have
$$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \dfrac{3}{4} \cdot 2 = \dfrac{3}{2}\text{.}$$

Comment: Wow , i feel like dumb now.

Comment: @Daman Believe me, it took years of tutoring and practice to realize you could use the joint density to find the expected value of only one of the variables. Don't be so hard on yourself.

Comment: I feel relaxed hearing that. After seeing solution it always look easy. Anyways thanks.Also i asked a question of application of neyman pearson lemma on hypothesis testing could you take a peek at it?

Comment: @Daman I'll try it out when I get home... but I can't promise anything there. I'm really rusty on that material.

Comment: I have a competitive exam on 11 feb my subject is mathematical statistics. Can i have a contact of you?I just wanna clear my doubts regarding my subject?I dont have a teacher around me.

Comment: @Daman Probably the best way for you to contact me (I haven't been checking e-mail very often lately, and e-mail is terrible for typing math) on this is to go to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) and ping me using `@Clarinetist`. Make sure you read how to view LaTeX in chat in the top right of the chat window. I'll respond when I can. Or, if you figure it out, you can open a chat room for the two of us.

Comment: I just started using stackexchange recently. How do i open a chat room for both of us?Also i dont have 20 reputation.I am in die hard need of help sir.

Comment: @Daman Ask in the chat room how to do it. People in there are very helpful. I can't remember how to do it currently.

Comment: okay doing it now.

Comment: Sir upvote any of my comment i ll get 5 reputation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71512/discussion-between-daman-and-clarinetist).